# constexpr algorithm all_of compiler error

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, constexpr

I have this small piece of code:

```
void all_of_examples() {
  using std::begin;
  using std::end;

  //C++17 
  //template< class InputIt, class UnaryPredicate >
  //constexpr bool all_of( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p );

  constexpr auto v2 = std::array<int, 4>{1, 1, 1, 1};
  constexpr auto eqOne = [](int x) constexpr { 
                          constexpr int one = 1;
                          return x == one; 
                       };

  constexpr bool isAllV2 = std::all_of(begin(v2), end(v2), eqOne);

  std::cout << isAllV2 << std::flush << '\n';
}
```

gcc-8 issues a diagnostic(clang issues a similar error as well):

> examples.cpp:21:41: error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'bool std::all_of(_IIter, _IIter, _Predicate) [with _IIter = const int*; _Predicate = algo::all_of_examples()::]'
>        constexpr bool isAllV2 = std::all_of(begin(v2), end(v2), eqOne);

I know that lamdas since C++17 can be constexpr and also `std::begin` && `std::end` are both marked as `constexpr`. Furthermore, `std::array` can also be constexpr. Therefore, why the compiler doesn't pick the constexpr version of `std::all_of` and complains that it isn't?

Comment: `all_of` is `constrexp` since C++20, have you used correct switch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::all_of` is only constexpr as of c++20. Also libstdc++ doesn't support this yet.

libc++ has support as of llvm-7 but even when using clang you probably still use libstdc++.

See:

- https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L508
- https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/release_70/include/algorithm#L925

Comment: Thank you so much your answer! I completely missed that.